# Passing a UITextFieldDelegate to UIViewController helper class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a helper class which looks something like this:

(We'll call this GUI.H & GUI.M Files)

**(DOT . H FILE )**

```
- (CGGroup)addLabelTextField:(UIViewController*)vc deligate:(id<UITextFieldDelegate>)deligate textField:(UITextField*)textField;
```

**(DOT . M FILE )**

```
- (CGGroup)addLabelTextField:(UIViewController*)vc deligate:(id<UITextFieldDelegate>)deligate textField:(UITextField*)textField
{

     // Blah, Blah Blah Blah Set Up & Configure Label & Textfield... 10 lines 

     // DONE Allocating & Configuring OK 

    // Last 3 Lines -- this is where the Deligate gets SET and the problems
    textField.delegate = deligate; // <- this is what is NOT happening
    [vc.self.view addSubview:textField]; // this adds TextField to passed in UIViewController
    return(cgTmp); // nothing to see here just a typedef of CGRect's

}
```

I pass a pointer of the ViewController, textField, and textFieldDeligate in and set them programmically (NO xib's what-so-ever)

Alloc, set, ect, is just like you would create / configure a textfield or label in the viewcontroller you were going to use it, except pass that the the helper class sets everything. so adding fields is one call, not all the usual configuring...

Problem:
Everything seems to be working fine, with the except that the TextFieldDeligate functions are NOT getting called (clang -- no warnings, nothing...)

If I move this same code, back into the calling class (uiViewController)
Suddenly, the delegates are getting called, no issues at all...

Another issue: once the testfield is set, you are not able to change things, I.E... SecureText = TRUE to FALSE.... Nothing happens, again when this code is moved back into the calling viewController, Suddenly everything works as advertised....

**I suspect something to do with the way the "UITextFieldDeligate" is being passed, but as I mentioned, clang doesn't give ANY warnings... NONE...**

The UIViewController is of course set up to support the deligates 
and the properties are declared...
(if I move this stuff back into the class (the UIViewController) (without having a separate class for these setting these fields) it works fine...

The method gets called:

**SomeUIViewController.M** (This is where we call the function defined in GUI.H & M)

```
[self.gui addTextField:self textField:self.passField deligate:self.passField.delegate];
```

AND YES There is a Property for the UITextField and the Class has the protocol declared

**SomeUIViewController.H**

```
@interface SomeUIViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) GuiUtils *gui;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *userField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *passField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *tmpField;
```

And as I mentioned b4, the only plroblem I'm experiencing is the deligate methods in the UIViewController (related to this UITextField) are NOT getting called...

(But I think it may be something simple, because I just noticed I'm not passing the deligate as a pointer... So it may have already been solved)

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: your method call makes no sense.Please post correct code.

Comment: This is the "method" call: "[self.gui addTextField:self textField:self.passField deligate:self.passField.delegate];" Which part do you not understand..? I'll be happy to explain it to you.

Comment: OK.... The Delegate NOT getting called is FIXED!  I was passing the delegate of the "UITextField.delegate" instead of the delegate of the UIViewController "self"  So the delegates NOW get called, but still having issues with setting certain attributes of the TextField after it's been Added to the subView... I cannot change the "textField.secureTextEntry" this is something else that works when the exact same code is moved into the calling UIViewController...

Answer (score 0):

OK.... The Delegate NOT getting called is FIXED! 
I was passing the delegate of the "UITextField.delegate" instead of the delegate of the UIViewController "self"

**FROM:**

```
[self.gui addTextField:self textField:self.passField deligate:self.passField.delegate];
```

**TO:**

```
[self.gui addTextField:self textField:self.passField deligate:self];
```